# How does FDE (Full Disk Encryption) work so quickly?

Tags: security, encryption, dmcrypt

I'm curious about how does Ubuntu's full disk encryption works under the hood. Here's an example:

Considering the following string as all the disk's content:

```
hello world
```

After applying some kind of encryption method it would look something like this:
*(I've used Caesar cipher with an shift of +1 for this example, e. g. A → B; B→C...)*

```
ifmmp xpsme
```

As I understand, when the computer is turned off, the drive's content would be the string above. But when it's turned back on, Ubuntu needs its content to be back again `hello world` in order to successfully boot.

What I don't really get is that in the *real world* the disk's content is way much more, and the encryption algorithm way more complex, and I find it difficult for the computer to completely encrypt/decrypt all of it in just a few seconds (it doesn't take longer to boot or to shut down).

How is this possible?

Comment: Don't bother reading the answers below.The short answer is that drives aren't decrypted on boot, which wouldn't make sense anyway, since you'd need to duplicate all your drives with decrypted versions. This happens below the file system level, on demand, as individual blocks are written to or read from the drive. Whether or not there's a performance degradation depends on a number of factors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## How does AES / Rijndael Encryption in general work?

This page has a fun [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html) that looks easy to understand, though it looks to be 50+ images, for example these two:

[image]

and

[image]

It's far too much to duplicate it all here, but if you have to have an all-in-one image it's this one:

[image]

---

Or, there's a more compact explanation at http://www.password-depot.com/know-how/blowfish_and_rijndael.htm

> The Rijndael encryption method is based on replacing, changing and
>   performing xor operations on bytes. The method looks like this:
>
> - From the 128-bit key, Rijndael generates 10 keys of 128 bits each.
> - These keys are placed into 4x4 arrays.
> - The plain text is also divided into 4x4 arrays (128 bits each).
> - Each of the 128-bit plain-text items is processed in 10 rounds (10 rounds for 128-bit-keys, 12 for 192, 14 for 256).
> - After the 10th round the code is generated.
> - Each single byte is substituted in an S box and replaced by the reciprocal on GF (2 8).
> - Then a bit-wise modulo-2 matrix is applied, followed by an XOR operation with 63.
> - The lines of the matrices are sorted cyclically.
> - The columns of the matrix multiplication are interchanged on GF (2 8).
> - The subkeys of each round are subjected to an XOR operation.
>
> The security level of this encryption method increases if Rijndael is
>   performed several times with different subkeys.

---

## How does Ubuntu's Full Disk Encryption work?

I *believe* it works by encrypting a partition with LUKS (default settings with AES), and then puts some volumes on it with LVM (like `/`, swap), and decrypts and mounts them at boot after you enter a passphrase. And there is a regular (not encrypted) boot partition that boots enough to ask for the passphrase.

[the_simple_computer's Guide to Full Disk Encryption with Ubuntu (Updated June 28, 2015)](https://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu) says that's about how the default installer's encryption works, and mentions that dual-booting wouldn't work (at least not out-of-the-box), the drive must use MBR so "*if your computer has UEFI, the distro will be installed in legacy BIOS mode so you can't use Secure Boot*" and "*also gives you a swap size equal to that of your system RAM (often unnecessary) and you have no choice over what kind of encryption is used.*"

---

## How fast is encryption?

If you run `cryptsetup benchmark` it will run tests and tell you about how fast the encryption alone takes, watch for the (currently) default aes-xts lines:

```
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-xts   256b    150.0 MiB/s    145.0 MiB/s
```

An average hard drive read speed could be 80-160 MB/s, so you won't be much longer than a regular read, and it's possible that the just-read sectors have already been decrypted while you're still be waiting for the hard drive to read more.

An SSD *could possibly* be faster, maybe 200-550MB/s, so you might notice  it. But, random reads could be slower, and I've read that SSD speeds can slow down after use (maybe when the drive fills up completely and it has to start "erasing" sectors?)

## ***How can the computer completely encrypt/decrypt all of the drive in just a few seconds (it doesn't take longer to boot or to shut down)?***

It doesn't have to decrypt everything first. The encryption (LUKS) works on **blocks of data**, can randomly decrypt any block, and acts like a layer between the drive's encrypted data and what the filesystem sees.

When the filesystem wants to see any block of data, LUKS decrypts that block first and then gives the decrypted data to the filesystem. You first wait for the drive to read the block of data (just like without using encryption), and **only have an extra delay for the decryption of that single block (or few blocks) of data** - and if the decryption is faster than the drive can read, the decryption *could* be finished before the drive reads the next block of data.

So just like a regular filesystem does not need to read the whole drive to read a file, when encryption is added it doesn't need to read the whole drive either, and it doesn't make things a *lot* slower.

The data on the hard drive is **always encrypted**, so there's nothing to do at shutdown except forget the key.

- There's more details on [Disk encryption theory on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory)

Comment: @Hewbot I've added some info (at the bottom) about the speed of decryption for files & blocks, since the title of your Q was edited to add *"so quickly?"* (is the title still what you wanted to ask?)

Answer (score 3):

This will be a bit of a simplification, but I'll try to go through the process of accessing a file on an encrypted filesystem.

For example, let's say a the beginning of the encrypted filesystem there's a file table; let's say we want to read `/foo.bar`. So, the first thing we do is read the beginning of the partition, decrypt it, and look through it for the file we want; let's say it says the file starts at 0x10000000 bytes. So to read, we start reading from the disk at that location and decrypting it; similarly, to write, we can encrypt the new contents, and write them at that new location.

Hopefully this helps clear up any confusion on the process.

Comment: I think this is the answer that actually answers the OP's question - his/her misconception is that it has to completely encrypt/decrypt the whole drive, not just the bits that get read/written as they are used.

Answer (score 2):

The processor uses dedicated instruction set. It is possible because of it, [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set). It enables fast encryption and decryption or you can say it cuts the overhead. It is fast because it is hardware implementation, as explained [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19544/how-exactly-does-aes-ni-work).

You can check about performance impacts [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=search&q=disk%20encryption) and they are worth it for added security.

Comment: In addition, data on the disk is only encrypted/decrypted as needed; for example, on boot, only startup scripts, user info, DM/WE executables, etc. are decrypted

Comment: Lots of CPU's do *not* have AES support, and Ubuntu's encryption still works on them... even if they did, this still doesn't really answer the question of how Ubuntu's Encryption works

Comment: @shsh Then, if I were on a really old computer, it would be impossible to use FDE, because there wouldn't be hardware implementation? Should I understand then that the whole disk is encrypt and decrypted on boot and shutdown?

Comment: @MagikM18 If so, how does the algorithm know where to start decrypting in the whole "string"? I mean, if I open a document, how does it know the "coordinates" where it is?

Comment: @Hewbot the same way it would anyway; basically, the encryption is a layer between the physical disk and the filesystem daemon. so, when it requests to read data from the disk, it is read then decrypted; so just like in a regular fs, it will first read the file table, find the starting position of the file, then read from there.

Comment: @MagikM18 Then, it's possible to read the system's files & directories tree even when the disk is encrypted?

Comment: @Hewbot with the key, you can read anything; without it, you can read nothing. Please see my newly posted answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Modern computers can do billions of operations per second, so it doesn't surprise me that encryption and decryption are fast.

This is how I would intuitively rank how fast computers are at doing things:

1. Doing calculations within memory (especially L1 and L2 memory), extremely fast
2. Reading from local storage, less fast (solid state disks are faster than hard disks)
3. Reading from the network, even less fast.

The other key bit to understand is that the operating does not need to decrypt the entire hard disk to boot the system. Rather, the operating system knows how to decrypt only the parts of the hard disk that it needs on the fly, and the same goes for writing.

So intuitively, I am not surprised that full disk encryption does not have much of an impact on performance, since I imagine the bottle-neck to be the disk.

Of course, these intuitions don't always match reality. For instance, in reality, there have been cases where full-disk encryption has caused a noticeable performance hit. But usually these are solved after the developers go through a few rounds of developing optimisations.

Comment: I can't find a way this answer is possible. Just copying 1TB with USB 3.0 takes some minutes, if a middle process has to be made (the decryption), it could take minutes to boot a computer with FDE.

Comment: @Hewbot I edited my answer to explain that decrypting happens on the fly. The OS does not need to read 1TB of data to start using an encrypted 1TB disk.